# How do i change the color for one container in a gridPaper to another color in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, web, flutter-layout

I am currently working on a pathfinding-visualizer-app and i am a bit overwhelmed by using a completely new programming language (at least for me).

But i think it is the best way to learn it as fast as possible.

To get to my problem:

I have a gridPaper with container Widgets. Every time i click on a container it changes the color from white to black.

So far so good...

For my pathfinding algorithm i need a 'start' and 'end' container (obviously a container where my algorithm starts searching for the end point).
Those i want to colorize in green (start) and red (end).
If i open the settings widget to click on "Start", it changes a "var = int" to 2 and then it goes to a switch case function.
From there if it gets a 1, it should print a black container, and if it gets a 2, it should fill the container green.
But then it starts to fill every container with the color green, because it goes through the complete offset ...

Do do have any ideas how to solve my problem ?

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final appTitle = 'Path Finder';
  final Color gridColor = Colors.lightBlue[100];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: MyHomePage(title: appTitle),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends HookWidget {
  final double cellSize = 20.0;
  final String title;
  var block = 1;
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  MyHomePage({
    Key key,
    this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _activated = useState<List<Offset>>([]);

    void _toggle(Offset offset) {
      if (!_activated.value.remove(offset)) _activated.value.add(offset);
      _activated.value = [..._activated.value];
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(title)),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTapDown: (details) => _toggle(details.localPosition ~/ cellSize),
        child: GridPaper(
          child: Stack(
            children: gridContainerMap(_activated),
          ),
          color: Colors.lightBlue[100],
          interval: cellSize,
          divisions: 1,
          subdivisions: 1,
        ),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
            DrawerHeader(
              child: Text('Einstellungen'),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Startpunkt'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                block = 2;
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Ziel'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...
                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Pathfinding-Algorithm'),
              onTap: () {
                // Update the state of the app
                // ...

                // Then close the drawer
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> gridContainerMap(ValueNotifier<List<Offset>> _activated) {
    switch (block) {
      case 1:
        return [
          Container(color: Colors.white),
          ..._activated.value.map((offset) {
            print('OFFSET: $offset');
            return coloringWallContainer(offset);
          }).toList(),
        ];
        break;

      case 2:
        return [
          Container(color: Colors.white),
          ..._activated.value.map((offset) {
            print('OFFSET: $offset');
            return coloringStartContainer(offset);
          }).toList(),
        ];
        break;

      default:
    }
  }

  Positioned coloringWallContainer(Offset offset) {
    return Positioned(
      left: offset.dx * cellSize,
      top: offset.dy * cellSize,
      width: cellSize,
      height: cellSize,
      child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.black),
    );
  }

  Positioned coloringStartContainer(Offset offset) {
    block = 1;
    return Positioned(
      left: offset.dx * cellSize,
      top: offset.dy * cellSize,
      width: cellSize,
      height: cellSize,
      child: ColoredBox(color: Colors.green),
    );
  }
}
```

Best regards
Robsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah nevermind, i just needed to know where i get the Offset from the next grid element...
After that it was relatively easy.